# Objective C "static" - is it the same as C++?

Tags: objective-c

I have inherited a codebase that has something very suspicious looking, and I can't work out if it's me being dumb or it's the mofer of all bugs. Here's the gist:

In base.h

```
@interface Base
{}
+(id)instance
@end
```

In base.m

```
+(id)instance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id me = nil;
    dispatch_once( &pred, ^{ me = [[self alloc] init] });
    return me;
}
```

In derived1.h

```
@interface Derived1 : Base {}
```

In derived2.h

```
@interface Derived2 : Base {}
```

The problem seems to be that the singleton is generated as follows:

```
[[Derived2 instance] foo];
```

This will surely set "`me`" to be of type `Derived2` forever, so what would happen if I invoked

```
[[Derived1 instance] bar];
```

Is this a race condition? Or does `static` mean something slightly different here?

Comment: What do you really want to know? It sounds like you're more worried about dispatch_once than static. In either case this is "everything is fine here," but the person answering the question could tailor it for you.

Comment: This is why the standard macro pattern for singletons is something like `#define singleton(shortClassName) static id shared##shortClassName; + (instancetype)shared##shortClassName { ... dispatch_once( ... shared##shortClassName = [[self alloc] init]; ... return shared##shortClassName; }`; singleton getters are not normally inherited.

Comment: It should be noted that your method does not implement a real *singleton* (nothing prevents you from allocating additional instances) but "only" a *shared instance*. Therefore it makes more sense to name the methods sharedBase, sharedDerived1, ... as @Tommy suggested above.

Comment: @StevenFisher what I want to know is what the code's author intended. Did he think he was creating a shared instance of Derived1 and another of Derived2? The actual classes seem to suggest that is the correct pattern, but it looks like that is not what he's done.

Comment: @JulianGold - What was the author's intention? Well my guess from the code you've provided is the same as yours - distinct instances - but you'll need to go through the code to try figure that out and then you might only be able to guess - mind reading is not an exact science ;-). There are some languages/platforms where it is possible, if obscure, for derived classes to get a distinct set of inherited "class variables" (generics in C# on .NET comes to mind), maybe your author comes from using such systems.

Comment: Good point. I misunderstood you. Yes, this method should not be in Base but rather in each of the classes. The code author's intent is unclear to me, so it's hard to figure out exactly how to fix it. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a "race condition" in the standard use of the term, but you are correct in that whichever of `[Base instance]`, `[Derived1 instance]` or `[Derived2 instance]` is called first determines the type of the object stored in the unique `me` variable.

The meaning of `static` is exactly the same as in C(++).

The solution is to change the declaration in `Base` to:

```
+ (instancetype) instance;
```

and to include the definition three times, once in each class:

```
+ (instancetype)instance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id me = nil;
    dispatch_once( &pred, ^{ me = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return me;
}
```

This way each of the three classes has its own method and its own static variable `me`. The use of `instancetype`, which tells the compiler that `instance` returns an object of the same type it was called on (this is the default for `init` family methods), improves the compile-time type checking.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

`static` is a C keyword.

As both, Objective-C and C++ are more or less just addons to the C programming language, `static` means the same in all three languages.

And yes, it is sort of a race condition in your code example. 
Which means as consequence, that your code will compile nicely but if Derived2 does not implement a method bar (but Derived1 does - for the compiler's sake) then you would run into an exception on runtime.

Comment: C++ has alternate meanings for `static`, doesn't it? But in this context, yes, same thing.

Comment: Not really. In C++ there are more levels of visibility. A static variable within a class has the scope of the class. It is effectively a class variable then. Witin plain C there are no classes but the principle is the same. A static variable can be visible within a function only but its duration continues between invocations of the function. So in principle it is the same but logically passed through to the OOP world of all the C-somethings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case `static` variables behave the same in C and C++ (and by extension Obj-C and Obj-C++) and your concern is correct.

Assuming the `+instance` class method hasn't been overridden, `+[Derived1 instance]` and `+[Derived2 instance]` will always return the same instance, and the type of that instance is determined by which was called first.

To provide a separate singleton for each subclass using this pattern, each subclass would have to override `+instance` and provide its own implementation.

Note:

- The contents of Derived1.h and Derived2.h are irrelevant here.  Check the .m files to see if `+instance` has been overridden.